# Permutation test aka randomization aka exact test . Terms of use?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, hypothesis-testing, distributions, mathematical-statistics

I am passing a course called “Statistical Thinking in Python” on one website. Now I am on the stage of the introduction to hypothesis testing.

Recently I came across one method of simulating a statistical hypothesis as permutation testing (also called randomization and exact test). In the context of where I learned about this method, a hypothesis was about the identical distribution of the considered indications (the results of elections for municipalities in the two regions) and the test statistic for this hypothesis was the equality of the average percentage of votes for a candidate.

The essence of the method was as follows: Two arrays of sizes $n$ and $m$ merged into one, then the order of elements was randomly changed, and the first $n$ elements were assigned to the first array, and the remaining ones to the second. The stat was considered.criterion and such mixing was performed a large number of times.

However, I do not understand the validity of this method and what hypotheses it can be used for? What is the difference with bootstrap test, or they are absolutely for different aims?

Comment: Which bootstrap test are you comparing with?